# How to Import another Py file to Qgis Plugin?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, import

i tried to import another py file to Current plugin in qgis  but its showing **No module named 'ProgressDialog'**

both files in same directory

Plugin Code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import (QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication,Qt)
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QProgressBar,QDialog
from qgis.core import QgsProject,QgsVectorFileWriter,Qgis
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .SplitLayerByAttribute_dialog import SplitLayerByAttributeDialog
import os.path,itertools
import PrograssDialog
```

PrograssDialog.py:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDialog

class PrograssDialog():
    def ShowDialog(self):
        self.Pd=QDialog()
        self.Pd.show()
```

How to Import another Py file to Qgis Plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
from .PrograssDialog import PrograssDialog
```

Comment: Why we use period(**.**PrograssDialog) what is purpose?

Comment: @VelugotiVenkateswarlu - One period to stay in same directory, two periods to go back one directory.